# Executor service or daemon threads which is better for multi threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon, load-testing

sorry for the long edit,

I am trying to download 100k urls and I started to download using executor service as below,

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    try {
        Callable callable = new Callable() {
            public List<String> call() throws Exception {
                //http connection
            }
        };
Future future = executorService.submit(callable);
```

but the above method is downloading the data only one url at a time..

and so I tried to create daemon threads (as shown below) and this method created muliple download connections (as expected) ..

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    Thread t = new Thread("loadtest " + i);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
}

while(true) {
    boolean flag = true;
    Set<Thread> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    for(Thread t : threads) {
        if(t.isDaemon() && t.getName().startsWith("loadtest")) {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag)
        break;
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Can the same method be used for load testing on servers ?

Any other suggestions of how load testing can be done will also be of great help..

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you research the difference between regular and daemon threads? What did you learn?

Comment: @JimGarrison yes i did a bit of research, the reason why I am creating daemon threads is for faster creation of more connections to the server.

Comment: Why do you believe daemon threads are created faster or allow more connections to the server?

Comment: @JimGarrison by faster i mean, say i am downloading data from 100k urls and run method has the code for data download, now if i download using executor service i am only able to download one url at a time, but if i use a daemon thread, i am able to create/download multiple download connections.

Comment: Sorry, none of that makes any sense.  An `ExecutorService` can be set up to run many threads in parallel.

Comment: @JimGarrison may be i asked it the wrong way, just give me a minute i will modify the question..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173037/discussion-between-arigato-manga-and-jim-garrison).

Comment: For loadtesting use tools like jmeter. You can even add your jar to jmeter and usw that jar logic for your test

Comment: It isn't a binary choice. You can have both. Daemon threads aren't faster than normal threads. The question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will hazard a guess that your `ExecutorService` is not working because you are calling `get()` on the `Future` instances it returns *inside your loop.* This mistake will indeed cause your processing to be serialized as if you had only one thread, because another task isn't submitted until the first completes.

If you really need to use `Callable`, don't `get()` the result until you are ready to block for some indefinite time as the tasks complete—and they can't complete if they haven't been submitted yet. For downloading URLs, it would be better to use `Runnable`, where the main thread submits URLs and then forgets about the task; the task can independently complete processing of its URL.

If you produce new tasks quickly, there's a chance you could queue up so many that you run out of memory. In that case, you can use a bounded queue and set up an appropriate rejection handler using [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) directly.

Comment: in many ways my question was not what i wanted to ask (dont know why) but your reply was what i wanted..thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A daemon thread is a thread which does not prevent JVM to exits when all other thread finished.

I believe if you want to wait for your main thread until the time daemon threads not finished then I suggest not to use daemon thread as it is supposed not be used for that use case.  You can use `Thread#join` to wait for your main thread.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    Thread t = new Thread("loadtest " + i);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
    t.join(); // main or parent thread will wait util the child thread finished 
}
```

I believe in your use case you should use normal thread instead of daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Load testing is not only about "hammering" your server with requests, well-behaved load test needs to represent **real user** using real browser with all associated stuff like:

- [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
- [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- [cache](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching)
- handling embedded resources (images, scripts, styles, fonts)

So I would recommend using a specialized [load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) which are capable of representing real user as close as possible and automatically taking care of aforementioned points. Also normally the load testing tools allow you to set [rendezvous points](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/FAQ/LoadRunner/What_is_a_rendezvous_point_.html) and provide a lot of metrics and charts so you will be able to see connect time, network latency, throughput, correlate increasing load with increasing response time/number of errors, etc.